# Are Static Methods and Static Variables Considered Class Members by JLS?

Tags: java

I want to know if static methods and static variables defined in a class are considered members of that class (or if the term 'member' means only instance variables/methods and inner classes)

Which members do classes consist of in Java?

Comment: _I felt like I found some inconsistencies._ Please clarify.

Comment: The usage agrees with the common definition of "member" in English. But yes the JLS doesn't make any kind of distinction either.

Comment: @Insignficant Person I know where you got confused. Instance variable vs class variable, members vs class members. In short member includes everything within a class, except the constructors.

Comment: @user3437460 Instance and static initializers are also not members.

Comment: @Voo Yes, thanks for pointing that out too.

Comment: @InsignificantPerson Anyway, to me, you question is valid. It is more on semantic. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Members consists of methods and all variables, be it static or not. However members do not include constructors.

---

In short, everything `(except the constructors)` within the class are members, be it inherited from a super class or not and be it static or non-static.

Comment: **Remark**: static/instance initializers are of course also not members of a class. What was defined within them are the members.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of member in the JLS as defined in [§8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8)  is:

> The body of a class declares members (fields and methods and nested
>   classes and interfaces),

So yes static or not, a field or a method is a member of the class. This coincides pretty well with what would commonly be understood as a "member" of something in English. What might be more up to debate is:

> The members of a class include both declared and inherited members

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.6 and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.2

Answer (score 1):

You talk about fields and methods and then quote about static classes, but anyway:

Static members are still members.

Quote from [JLS 8.1.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.6)

> ```
> ClassMemberDeclaration:
>     FieldDeclaration 
>     MethodDeclaration 
>     ClassDeclaration 
>     InterfaceDeclaration 
>   ;
> ```

A Field declaration for example is [specified here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-FieldDeclaration)

> ```
> FieldDeclaration:
>   {FieldModifier} UnannType VariableDeclaratorList ;
> ```

With finally the [FieldModifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-FieldModifier) possibly including `static`

> ```
> FieldModifier:
>   (one of) 
>   Annotation public protected private 
>   static final transient volatile
> ```